# On a certain day in the daily job schedule i get the error The transaction log for database dbname is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

Tags: sql, ssis, database-administration

I have a batch job that executes fine on daily basis but the job that runs from Friday night to Saturday morning gives me the following error:

> The transaction log for database 'Db name' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION' and fails execution.

Could you please help me to understand the issue ?

Comment: what's the content of the batch file?

Comment: no batch file is involved in it basically the level where the issue happens it calls for an explicit transaction in the execute sql task starting with a delete statement  then starting an insert of data into destination tabel from an join query over various tables which is the source.

Comment: do you truncate the log file?

Comment: my db recovery is in simple recovery mode , so i believe it automatically configures the truncation process for log file using checkpoints...but i didnt do that manually. however if you have any suggestions in this area let me know

Comment: if simple recovery then you have to manually truncate the log file, this only happens if you have active transaction that is way out of your hands

Comment: ok then what can be the solution to handle this

Comment: execute dbcc truncate option

Comment: cannot truncate Active transactions, i have added another log file on some other disk for now will have to check this friday if it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the data in small batches instead of a single transaction.

```
While (@RecordCount > 0)
  BEGIN
       DELETE top 5000 FROM <<TABLE>>
       <<where condition>>
     SET @RecordCount = @@RowCount
  END
```